# Получить cookie у django

Tags: python, cookie, django

Как получить список cookie и  session у django внутри класса

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    pass
```

при работе с Class-based views (CBV)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать self.request, который содержит COOKIES и session.